# python "upgrade" connection from HTTP to TCP, how?

Tags: python, docker, rest, sockets

I want to write a python program to execute an interactive command within docker container. SSH into the container is out of the question because I cannot modify the container. I am looking into the exec API.

I can issue the exec API without issue and obtain the exec instance Id. But upon calling the exec start API (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ExecStart), the call simply stucks:

```
url = "https://" + server_ip + "/docker/exec/" + id + "/start"
d = {'Detach': False, 'Tty': True}
h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, headers = h, data = json.dumps(d), verify=False)
print(r.status_code)
```

Here is what I see when I interrupt:

```
    r = requests.post(url, headers = h, data = json.dumps(d), verify=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
    r.content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 831, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 753, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 572, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 764, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 694, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 451, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 754, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 641, in read
```

If I set `Detach` to True, it will return 200 but it won't work for interactive command.

I actually have some additional operation I planned on doing that I also cannot execute "docker exec" command from python. So I really want to get python to use docker's API.  What do I need to do to get python "upgrade" the REST connection into a TCP connection?

Comment: Can you adapt the program to have an HTTP interface, or some other network-accessible endpoint?  Then you could interact with the application through its exposed port, rather than trying to use a debugging-oriented interface that requires administrator privileges.

Comment: Are you looking for WebSockets? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I want to write a program to execute an interactive command within docker container. I can only interact with the docker container via a web server, if websocket works, so be it. But how? @David, I can't make any change to the container, if that's what you meant.